# Modifying an existing Calendar Event from HtmlService input

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to add a "Sign Up" link to a Google Calendar Event where upon clicking the user is prompted via HtmlService to submit their email address. Their email address is then added to the event.

Here's [a similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235794/how-to-add-add-invite-me-link-in-google-calendar). What I'd like to do differently is use HtmlService to have the user input their email address, which then is passed back to GAS to be added to the Calendar Event in question. That way they can choose the email they want (instead of whatever Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() returns) to sign up with. (and by sign up, I mean get added to the guest list - they still have to accept the invite, but that's fine).

Is this possible? I'm not seeing any examples of this so maybe there's a better way?

I am starting to tear out what little hair I have. I've included my latest sample code, where I pass the event object into the HTML template. It's not throwing an error, but it's not working either. Thank you in advance!!

Code.gs:

```
function doGet(event) {
  //    // shorten the event parameter path;
 var param = event.parameter;
//    // get the calendar event id passed in the query parameter
 var eventId = param.eId;
 var calId = param.calId;
 var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
 var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
 t.eObj = cal.getEventById(eventId);
 return t.evaluate();
}

function addEmail(emObj,myForm){
  var guestEmail = myForm.user;
  emObj.addGuest(guestEmail)
}
```

and Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function update() {
        alert("Success!");
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm">
      <input id="userEmail" name="user" type="text" />
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(update).addEmail(eObj,this.form)" />
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have scriptlets in your html file, so you don't need to evaluate a template.  I've added another 2 input fields for the calId and eventId.  They get replaced in the HTML before being served.  Then the event ID and Cal ID are passed back in the form object.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function update() {
        alert("Success!");
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm">

      <input id="userEmail" name="user" type="text" />

      <input name="calId" type="text" style="display:none"
        value="zzz_calID_zzz"/>
      <input name="eventId" type="text" style="display:none"
        value="zzz_eventID_zzz"/>


      <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(update)
            .addEmail(this.form)" />
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

### doGet:

```
function doGet(event) {
  //    // shorten the event parameter path;
 var param = event.parameter;
//    // get the calendar event id passed in the query parameter
 var eventId = param.eId;
 var calId = param.calId;

 var t = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index').getContent();

 t = t.replace('zzz_calID_zzz',calId);
 t = t.replace('zzz_eventID_zzz',eventID);

 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(t);
}
```

### Server code:

```
function addEmail(myForm){

  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(myForm.calId);
  var event = cal.getEventById(myForm.eventId);
  var guestEmail = myForm.user;

  event.addGuest(guestEmail)
}
```